# How to process these 2 dictionaries to get a new dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have these 2 dictionaries;

```
Dict1 = {1: ('John', 37), 2: ('Tom', 23), 3: ('Tom', 19), 4: ('Jane', 58)}
Dict2 = {1: ('2',), 2: ('4',), 3: ('19',)}
```

The output dictionary from processing the above 2 dictionaries is;

```
OutputDict = {1: ('John', 37), 2: ('Tom', 23)}
```

The logic in getting `OutputDict` is like this;

(1) `Dict1` and `Dict2` must have matching keys. If not, `OutputDict` will discard the key:value pair from `Dict1`.
(2) If a matching key is found, the 2nd element in the value of `Dict1` must be different from the value in `Dict2`. If they are the same, `OutputDict` will discard the key:value pair from `Dict1`.

How can this be programmed in Python? I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are you having a specific conceptual problem with formulating a solution?

Comment: I am wondering if I should use a for loop or whether there is a more pythonic way to solve this problem.

Comment: @user3293156 Until you're really familiar with List/Dict Comprehension always start with a for loop and then figure out if the logic is simple enough to drop into a Comprehension of some sort.  For more complex Comprehensions I still will write out the for loops first, this way I have an output that I can compare to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [dictionary comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to iterate through the key-value pairs in `Dict1`, only keeping those key-value pairs such that (1) the key is in `Dict2`; and (2) the numeric value matches `Dict1` and `Dict2`:

**Demo**

```
>>> OutputDict = { k: v for k, v in Dict1.iteritems()
                   if k in Dict2 and int(Dict2[k][0]) != v[1] }
>>> OutputDict
{1: ('John', 37), 2: ('Tom', 23)}
```

Comment: +1: I like this one better than the other dict comprehension answer, mainly because the person asking the question obviously is newer to python, and this actually gives some explanation and not just "the answer"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I definitely need it. However, the amazing speed at which I get answers from the experts in stack overflow is disheartening. So fast until I think I am unfit to be a programmer. How to match you guys? Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
Dict1 = {1: ('John', 37), 2: ('Tom', 23), 3: ('Tom', 19), 4: ('Jane', 58)}
Dict2 = {1: ('2',), 2: ('4',), 3: ('19',)}
OutputDict = {k: v for (k, v) in Dict1.iteritems() if k in Dict2 and v[1] != int(Dict2[k][0])}
print OutputDict
```

Output:

```
{1: ('John', 37), 2: ('Tom', 23)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using zip:

```
outDict = {i:Dict1[i] for i,j in zip(Dict1.keys(),Dict2.keys()) if i==j and int(Dict1[i][1]) != int(Dict2[i][0])}
```

Output:

```
 {1: ('John', 37), 2: ('Tom', 23)}
```